# How to store a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary in realm-dotnet

Tags: c#, uwp, realm

I m trying to integrate Realm .NET in my uwp project and I would like to know if there is any way to store a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary in realm-dotnet base.
I tried this :

```
 public class Training : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_document { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string>  Names { get; set;}
}
```

But I m getting this error :

Error       Fody/RealmWeaver: Training.Name is a 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2' which is not yet supported.

Thanks for advance,

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Same Error as the IDictionary : Error Fody/RealmWeaver: Training.Name is a 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2' which is not yet supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Base request

There isn't a way to directly store a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` into Realm.
On the Realm official website you can find all the informations that you're searching, as an example, [here](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#supported-types) you can find the full list of the supported data types (Collections too).

In order to save data with a structure as kind as a `Dictionary`, you would want to use a custom class that inherits from `RealmObject` with two `IList<T>` properties, such as:

```
public class RealmDictionary : RealmObject {
    public IList<T> Keys { get; }
    public IList<T> Values { get; }
}
```

An in your class where you want to store the `Dictionary`, use an instance of the above `RealmDictionary` class:

```
...
public RealmDictionary Names { get; set; }
...
```

### Update

(Using [NewtonsoftJson](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json))
  If you must serialize the data into a Json string, you can setup your base class as:

```
...
[JsonIgnore]
public RealmDictionary RealmNames { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string,string> Names {
    get {
        return RealmNames.AsDictionary
    }   
}
...
```

Then adding into the `RealmDictionary` class a property/method that constructs a dictionary with the values, something along the lines..

```
public Dictionary<string,string> AsDictionary {
    get {
        Dictionary<string,string> temp = new Dictionary<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < Keys.Count; i++){
            temp.Add(Keys[i], Values[i]);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a little difference that when we declare it as a  RealmObject we cannot use it for this type of structure :
"trainings": {
"key1" : "Value1",
"key2" : "Value2",
"key3" : "Value3"
}

Comment: Because you must serialize the data into a Json string?

Comment: Yes exactly it's for that !

Comment: @HamzaBouzidi check the update part of the answer! It should help

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZzAtomiic

Comment: @HamzaBouzidi just helping, remember to accept the answer if helped :)

Comment: Just can you tell me how should I set the Names please ?

Comment: You don't need to set the names because its a readonly property, you just need to set the RealmNames instance by instantiating a new RealmDictionary. You can populate the RealmDictionary.Keys property by assigning to it a `new List<string>(Dictionary.Keys)` and the RealmDictionary.Values as well (`new List<string>(Dictionary.Values)`). The `Dictionary` being your original dictionary.

Comment: But the get method of the  Dictionary<string,string> Names attribute is throwing a  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. because the RealmNames is null

Comment: Obviously, you have to set up the RealmNames property first, as i mentioned in the previous comment. If you have other problems make a new question, because those problems are not explicitly related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This throws an error where it cant find "T"

```
public class RealmDictionary : RealmObject 
{
    public IList<T> Keys { get; }
    public IList<T> Values { get; }
}
```

The correct way of doing this is to add a `<T>` in front of the class name if you want both the keys and values to be of the same type.

```
public class RealmDictionary<T> : RealmObject 
{
    public IList<T> Keys { get; }
    public IList<T> Values { get; }
}
```

If you want the key to be of a different type than the value then it would look something like

```
public class RealmDictionary<T, K> : RealmObject 
{
        public IList<T> Keys { get; }
        public IList<K> Values { get; }
}
```

Also for the same type of keys and values the implementation

```
public RealmDictionary Names { get; set; }
```

would actually throw an exception.

Right way to do it would be

```
public RealmDictionary<"TYPE THAT YOU WANT"> Names { get; set; }
```

For eg.

```
public RealmDictionary<string> Names { get; set; }
```

For different type of keys and values the implementation looks like this

```
public RealmDictionary<string, object> Names { get; set; }
```

So your **Keys** will be of type ***String*** and the **Values** it maps to will be of type ***Object***