# IDictionary Property in RealmObject

Tags: .net, dictionary, realm

I would like to know if some has a solution for IDictionary<K,V> properties in RealmObject classes. The best I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150084/how-to-store-a-system-collections-generic-dictionary-in-realm-dotnet/49150384#49150384). I don't know if this worked previously, but I had the same idea and it doesn't seem to work (anymore), or they didn't post all information needed. Looks like a class inheriting RealmObject can not be generic. If I implement the dictionary with fixed types it works. But then I would have to do this for every type combination I need. In other words this works

```
public class MyDictionary : RealmObject, IDictionary<string,string>
{
    public IList<string> Keys { get; }
    public IList<string> Values { get; }
}
```

but this doesn't

```
public class MyDictionary<K,V> : RealmObject, IDictionary<K,V>
{
    public IList<K> Keys { get; }
    public IList<V> Values { get; }
}
```

Maybe someone here knows how to do it, I couldn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "easy" way to do it unfortunately. There are workarounds, but they are fairly convoluted - e.g. you can create a `RealmObject` inheritor that contains all primitive types:

```
enum ValueType
{
    String,
    Int,
    // Remaining types...
}

class DictionaryValue : RealmObject
{
    public string StringValue { get; private set; }
    public int IntValue { get; private set; }
    // ...

    // Private persisted property to hold the type.
    private int ValueTypeInternal { get; set; }

    public ValueType Type => (ValueType)ValueTypeInternal;
    
    // Private ctor to avoid instantiating it directly
    private DictionaryValue() {}

    public static DictionaryValue Create<T>(T value)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return new DictionaryValue
            {
                ValueTypeInternal = (int)ValueType.String,
                String = (string)(object)value
            };
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have a "Dictionary" object look like:

```
class RealmDictionary : RealmObject
{
    private int KeyTypeInternal { get; set; }
    private int ValueTypeInternal { get; set; }

    public ValueType KeyType => (ValueType)KeyTypeInternal;
    public ValueType ValueType => (ValueType)ValueTypeInternal;

    private IList<DictionaryValue> Keys { get; }
    private IList<DictionaryValue> Values { get; }

    public void Add<K, V>(K key, V value)
    {
        // Verify that KeyType == K and ValueType == V

        Keys.Add(DictionaryValue.Create(key));
        Values.Add(DictionaryValue.Create(value));
    } 
}
```

And your real dictionary implementation would be an unmanaged class that wraps this dictionary. Note that the Realm SDK plans to add native support for `IDictionary<string, RealmValue>` in the near future, so you might want to wait until that lands - while it doesn't support non-string key types, you can emulate those by serializing the value to string.